# Issue with step taken during proof of $A \subset X$ then $\overline{A} = \bigcap(A + V)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a topological vector space.

If $A \subset X$ then $\overline{A} = \bigcap(A + V)$, where $V$ runs through all neighborhoods of $0$.

**Proof**

$x \in \overline{A}$ if and only if $(x + V) \cap A \neq \emptyset$

for every neighborhood $V$ of $0$.

(I am fine up to here, the next part is what I don't get)

This happens if and only if $x \in A - V$ for every such $V$.

I can't see how that conclusion is reached.

$x$ can't be in $A - V$ for every $V$ neighborhood of $0$ as consider the situation when we have a set $A$ that contains $0$. Then $V = A$ itself is one such neighborhood. Then $A - V = \emptyset$ which obviously does not contain $x$.

So what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: The above is set subtraction, not set difference. Similar words, dissimilar meaning.

Comment: Cheers, fixed it now.

Comment: By the way, it is not true that $A-V = \emptyset$. This minus sign does not mean difference of sets, but means $\{ a-v: a \in A, v \in V \}$ which is obviously not empty. In particular, since $0 \in V$, you have that $A = \{a-0 :a \in A\} \subset A -V$. Moreover, if $V$ is a neighbourhood of $0$, so is $-V$, so you are done.

Comment: Ah I see what's happening now, thanks!

Comment: @Crostul: mind posting that as an answer?